# With 2 textboxes how do you disable a text box once one text box is typed in

Tags: html, angular, typescript

I have two text boxes. One for Name and one for Number. What I want is for only one to have input in it at a time. So for instance if the user selected name and started typing then the number textbox would disable. I am trying to implement this without the use of buttons and simply just if name textbox has text disable number textbox vice versa. This is what I had below and it does not work. Is there a way to do this simpler? Or a way to only have it in the HTML. I am stuck help is appreciated thank you.

```js
function changetextbox() {
  if (document.getElementById("name").value !== "null") {
    document.getElementById("number").disable = 'true';
  } else {
    document.getElementById("number").disable = 'false';
  }
  if (document.getElementById("number").value !== "null") {
    document.getElementById("name").disable = 'true';
  } else {
    document.getElementById("name").disable = 'false';
  }
}
```

```html
<input type="text" name="enterName" id="name" placeholder="Enter Name" />
<input type="text" name="enterNumber" id="number" placeholder="Enter Number" />
```

Comment: Please, use an "Angular way" -[(ngModel)] and [disabled]-

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the angular forms - https://angular.io/guide/forms

But in short you could do the following - where you coerce the string value into a boolean and disable the formControl if a value exists for the other input.

```
<form>
  <input type="text" [(ngModel)]="name" name="name" [disabled]="!!number">
  <input type="text" [(ngModel)]="number" name="number" [disabled]="!!name">
</form>
```

**Your TS file**

```
export class ClassName implements OnInit {
    name: string;
    number: string;
}
```

Comment: when I do this it does not recognize "name" or "number". I get "Property 'name' does not exist on type 'CreateNewComponent'", do I need to declare these somewhere?

Comment: Yes you will need to declare these within your typescript file associated with the component.

Comment: When I do this I am still getting errors. How would you declare them?

Comment: @cekborg I have edited my answer to show you. Basically because [(ngModel)] is something called two way databinding. It is accessing & updating the value in your components typescript, that is why they need to be declared. So you need to add the two variable declarations inside your class.

Comment: If you are getting not declared errors you have put them two variables in the wrong place. Put them under the class for the component you are working on (the same component your inputs are in). Dont copy the export class but just the two variable declarations. Alternatively you may have to import the FormsModule into your component Module if you have not already done this.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this

```js
window.addEventListener("load", function() { // on page load
  const nmb = document.getElementById("number"),
    name = document.getElementById("name")
  document.getElementById("myForm").addEventListener("input", function(e) {
    const tgt = e.target;
    const otherField = tgt.id === "name" ? nmb : name;
    otherField.disabled = tgt.value !== ""
  });
});
```

```html
<form id="myForm">
  <input type="text" name="enterName" id="name" placeholder="Enter Name" />
  <input type="text" name="enterNumber" id="number" placeholder="Enter Number" />
</form>
```

Comment: This does not disable the other when one has text in it. I want it stay disable until both no longer have text in it. Do you know how to do this?

Comment: @mplungjan, Please, use an "Angular way": -[(ngModel)] and [disabled]-

Answer (score 0):

```js
let name = document.getElementById("name");
let number = document.getElementById("number");

function inputfunction() {
  if (name.value.length > 0) {
    number.disabled = true;
  } else if (number.value.length > 0) {
    name.disabled = true;
  } else {
    name.disabled = false;
    number.disabled = false;
  }
}



name.addEventListener('input', inputfunction);
number.addEventListener('input', inputfunction);
```

```html
<input type="text" name="enterName" id="name" placeholder="Enter Name" />
<input type="text" name="enterNumber" id="number" placeholder="Enter Number" />
```

Comment: When I put this in my ts file it gives me a bunch of errors. For the first 'Let' it says "Unexpected token. A constructor, method, accessor, or property was expected". For name and number it says "Object is possibly 'null'". For disabled it says "Property 'disabled' does not exist on type 'HTMLElement'" and for value it says "Property 'disabled' does not exist on type 'HTMLElement'".  Do I need to declare any of these?

Comment: @Dibash, the question is about Angular, not JavaScript

Answer (score 0):

You can use angular focus and focusout directives.

.HTML file

```
<input type="text" name="enterName" id="name" placeholder="Enter Name" [disabled]="!isNameFocused" (focus)="onFocus()" (focusout)="onFocusOut()"/>

<input type="text" name="enterNumber" id="number" placeholder="Enter Number" [disabled]="!isNumberFocused" (focus)="onFocusOut()" (focusout)="onFocus()" />
```

.TS file

```
isNameFocused: boolean = true;
isNumberFocused: boolean = false;

  onFocus() {
    this.isNameFocused = true;
    this.isNumberFocused = false;
  }

  onFocusOut() {
    this.isNumberFocused = true;
    this.isNameFocused = false;
  }
```

Comment: This is close. When I do this it only allows me to click on the name textbox initially before I can enter anything in the number textbox. ( I want both to be shown right away and once characters are entered it will disable the other one completely until both are empty again.) Also when I type in one and if I double click on the other I am able to type in both. It doesn't fully disable any of them